# Why do some SQL Server databases go into a "Recovery Pending" state after shutting down / restarting on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, sql-server-2019

I built a secondary PC from old parts as a server for SQL Server databases and I went with Linux/Ubuntu 20.04 because it's free. I knew it would not be easy to set this up (I'm rather a Windows user) and I had quite some issues/challenges along the way but I got it working.

My only headache now is that basically every time I shutdown or reboot the PC, some of the databases are getting the "Recovery pending" state and then I have to run the usual script to fix that. (which for some of my big DBs are taking quite a long time to finish)

I thought I need to manually stop the SQL Server services every time I shutdown the PC so I tried this before that:

```
sudo systemctl stop mssql-server
```

Yet I still had one of the DBs in this pending state after booting. Now maybe the issue is that that DB is on a different drive? The DBs not affected by this state are on the main SSD where Ubuntu is installed, if that makes any difference.

Thanks for any helpful feedback.

Comment: Is, perhaps, the SQL Server service starting before the drives are mounted? That would cause such a scenario. When you say a different drive, I assume you mean a second storage device in the host. You don't mean a network storage or external storage location, do you?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that briefly but I don't know linux that well, is it possible? The drives are internal storage devices, 1 SSD + 2 HDD.

Comment: I think your question is better suited for either [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) sites.

Comment: Will try that, thanks.